# Executing dynamic query inside a scalar function sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a scalar function in SQL Server. I have coined up the select statement as follows:

```
SET @Statement1 = 'SELECT 1 FROM ' + @p_TableName + 
                  ' WHERE RegionTypeID = 1 AND RegionID = ' + 
                  CONVERT (nvarchar (50), @p_RegionID)
```

Here @`p_TableName` is the name of the table (nvarchar (500)) and @`p_RegionID` is a uniqueidentifier.

I am now executing the above statement as follows:

```
EXEC @ReturnValue1 = @Statement1
```

WHERE `@ReturnValue1` is int.

But when I call this function from elsewhere I get this error:

> The name 'SELECT 1 FROM [PS].[Availability] WHERE RegionTypeID = 1 AND
>   RegionID = AF4C182C-F751-41AD-AA6A-20A50A7A38C8' is not a valid
>   identifier.

I need to know how I can call a dynamic sql select statement from within a scalar function.

Comment: Dynamic sql is not permitted in UDFs. Check [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#UDF) for a good reference on the topic.

Comment: Thanks...Can you please suggest a workaround for my problem? Is there any other way with which I can write the select statement given above? All I need is to know if the RegionTypeID and RegionID is present?

Comment: @SarinGopalan you can use stored procedure (SP) instead of function. The results of SP can be written in table then, if you need that.

Comment: I need to use this function along a select statement...so I have to stick to functions only!

Comment: @SarinGopalan check my answer, after executing SP you wil get single value that you can use next in some other query. If this is not what you need, please, specify what you need to do with the output you get.

Answer (score 4):

You can create SP like below with output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcNameGoesHere 
    @p_TableName nvarchar(500),
    @p_RegionID uniqueidentifier,
    @output int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Statement1 nvarchar(max), 
            @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)

    SET @Statement1 = N'SELECT @someValue = 1 FROM ' + @p_TableName + 
                      ' WHERE RegionTypeID = 1 AND RegionID = ' + 
                      CONVERT (nvarchar (50), @p_RegionID)  
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@someValue int OUTPUT'

    EXEC sp_executesql @Statement1, @ParmDefinition, @output=@someValue OUTPUT 

    RETURN;

END
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
DECLARE @output int

EXEC ProcNameGoesHere '[PS].[Availability]','AF4C182C-F751-41AD-AA6A-20A50A7A38C8', @output OUTPUT

SELECT @output
```

Or:

```
IF ISNULL(@output,0) = 1
BEGIN
    --Do something here
END
```

Comment: My pleasure! If answer is useful, feel free to upvote/accept it, it is the great way to say thank you! :)